# Problem with linebreak in combination with strikeout from the ulem package and newcommand

Tags: macros, lyx, hyphenation, ulem

Is it possible to combine the "result" of a newcommand with the sout command of the ulem package with working linebrak/hyphenation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem,lipsum}
\textwidth=3cm % just to force hyphenation/linebreaks to happen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
 \sout{The sout makro of ulem is able to handle hyphenation and linebreaks in text entered directly but not as macro see next line!}
 \sout{\lipsum[1]}
 \newcommand\test{Nore does it work with a simple macro text.}
 \sout{\test}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces the following output.
[image: Output for code with the linebreakproblem]

as TeXnician suggested in the simplest form it works like this:

```
\newcommand\souttest{\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\test}}
\souttest
```

I've tried to implement this to my situation which ist slightly more complicated. I have a Lyx "local Format" defined to highlight text and to make annotations to have a convenient way to do QCAmap and reduce ERT in Lyx! So the simply version of the Problem is:

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname soutAutoP\endcsname{\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\csname test\endcsname}}
\soutAutoP
```

For those interested the long version it is as follows:

```
InsetLayout Flex:Kategorie
  LyxType               charstyle
  LabelString           kategorie
  LatexType             command
  LatexName             kategorie
Argument 1
  Decoration conglomerate
  LabelString    "Name"
  Tooltip        "Eindeutiger Kategorie Name"
  Mandatory 1
EndArgument
Argument 2
  LabelString    "Phra"
  Tooltip        "Text der Phrase"
  Mandatory 1
EndArgument
Argument 3
  LabelString    "Gen"
  Tooltip        "Text der Generalisierung"
  Mandatory 1
EndArgument
Preamble
  \usepackage{ifthen}
  \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \newcommand{\KatFarbe}[1]
  {
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\colorlet{myColor}{blue}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\colorlet{myColor}{lime}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\colorlet{myColor}{orange}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{\colorlet{myColor}{cyan}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{\colorlet{myColor}{purple}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{F}}{\colorlet{myColor}{red}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\colorlet{myColor}{magenta}}.{\colorlet{myColor}{gray}}}}}}}}
 }
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \newcommand\encircle[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}
    \newcommand{\kategorie}[4]{%
    \expandafter\gnewcommand\csname Kat#1\endcsname{\hspace{0pt}#4}%
    \expandafter\gnewcommand\csname Kat#1P\endcsname{\hspace{0pt}#2}%
    \expandafter\gnewcommand\csname soutKat#1P\endcsname{\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\csname Kat#1P\endcsname}}%
    \expandafter\gnewcommand\csname Kat#1G\endcsname{\hspace{0pt}#3}%
      \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\myKat]\KatFarbe{\myKat}\linelabel{lne:#1}\linelabel{lne:#1Start}\textcolor{myColor!80!black}{\expandafter\csname Kat#1\endcsname$^{\tiny\encircle{\myKat}}$}\linelabel{lne:#1Stop}}
 EndPreamble
 End
```

With this code you get a new Command in Lyx like this:
[image: Screenshot of the command at work within Lyx]

You get an output like this:
[image: Snipped of the PDF output of the command]

To access the reduced text with the sout one can write:

```
\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\KatCSexEtwP}
%to reduce the ERT I tried to combine it to
\soutKatCSexVsKoerperP
```

But I failed.
As for the question of TeXnician I honestly don't know because I'm not that deep in TeX. Sorry!

Sorry for the German in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy for a simple new command as in your example, just add `\expandafter` (which won't work for `\lipsum` btw):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem,lipsum}
\textwidth=3cm % just to force hyphenation/linebreaks to happen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
 \sout{The sout makro of ulem is able to handle hyphenation and linebreaks in text entered directly but not as macro see next line!}
 \sout{\lipsum[1]}
 \newcommand\test{Nore does it work with a simple macro text.}
 \expandafter\sout\expandafter{\test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a common solution for more complicated macros like lipsum?

Comment: I tried to implement your solution to my "real" problem which is in it's simplest form like this: \expandafter\newcommand\csname soutAutoP\endcsname{\expandafter\sout\expandafter{\csname test\endcsname}} but in this case the solution doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreasOberreiter How is your command defined (the test one)? Is it expandable (it will only work with expandable commands)?

Comment: @AndreasOberreiter Btw: Please do not add your problem in my post (this site works differently: please edit your question).