# Multiple line strikeout with ulem/soul and newcommand

Tags: overleaf, soul, ulem

I'm having a hard time doing a strikeout of a multi-line text within a newcommand using ulem and soul.

The answers below were not helpful:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74910/265141  % Multi-line word with hyphenation
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430295/265141 % Adding `\expandafter`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\HW}[1]{\textcolor{green}{(HW) #1} }
\newcommand{\WH}[1]{\textcolor{red}{(WH) #1} }

\begin{document}

MWE

% This is ulem
\HW{\sout{\WH{Hello, World! This is a long paragraph so we get multiple lines. It seems this can be difficult to handle by packages and I'm not sure why.}} Do you know?}

Thanks!

% This is soul. It raises an error of unmatched brackets
\WH{\st{\HW{World, Hello! This is a long paragraph so we get multiple lines. It seems this can be difficult to handle by packages and I'm not sure why.}} Do you know?} 

% The below should not print red
Thanks!

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE showing undesired behaviour.]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the command `\st` must see the text *directly* (not hidden behind any macro) for it to work.  Any `\textcolor` must go outside.

So one option is to write

```
\WH{\textcolor{green}{\st{World, Hello! This is a long paragraph so we get multiple lines. It seems this can be difficult to handle by packages and I'm not sure why.}} Do you know?}
```

It's not impossible to extend the `\st` macro to handle a few more special cases, but being completely general is very difficult.

Alternatively use `lua-ul` package, which uses some special abilities of LuaLaTeX to implement the functionality.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\newcommand{\HW}[1]{\textcolor{green}{(HW) #1} }
\newcommand{\WH}[1]{\textcolor{red}{(WH) #1} }

\begin{document}

MWE

\WH{\strikeThrough{\HW{World, Hello! This is a long paragraph so we get multiple lines. It seems this can be difficult to handle by packages and I'm not sure why.}} Do you know?} 

Thanks!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Link to some related questions 
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629950) (contain lua-ul  example) 
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430291) 
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480113) 
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/652226) 
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637087)