# Adding strikeout to a \newenvironment command

Tags: fonts, environments, strikeout

We have defined a new environment to allow us to mark large blocks of text:

```
\newenvironment{deletedParagraphs}{\par\color{red}}{\par}
```

That environment works great to color the text red, but now we'd also like that text to use a strikeout font. None of my google searches have yielded a way to do this with `\newenvironment`. I've seen answers on using packages for tracking changes, as we currently do, but what we use has limitations such as failing to handle sections with a `\cite` key), whereas using `\newenvironment` works for large blocks of text.

All I can't do is make the text strikeout.

Related questions that didn't seem to have an answer specific to `\newenvironment`:

- [Environment to underline/strikeout for comparing versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64744/environment-to-underline-strikeout-for-comparing-versions)
- [Strikethrough text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text)

I've tried using the `environ` package as suggested in the comments. So far I haven't succeeded, but I'm sure I haven't spent enough time with the documentation. I'll update that is as go, but here's a minimal reproducible example of what doesn't work so far as I've gotten:

What I'd like is the first section to be red strikethrough, and the second section to be blue and not strikethrough. I need to be able to include things like `\cite{...}` in the paragraphs within the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{deletedParagraphs}{\color{red}{\sout{\BODY}}}{}
\NewEnviron{addedParagraphs}{\color{blue}{\BODY}}{}

% This was my first attempt that didn't play well with sout
% \newenvironment{deletedParagraphs}{\color{red}}{}
% \newenvironment{addedParagraphs}{\color{blue}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{deletedParagraphs}
Example deleted section - notice word wrap is no longer functioning when this text is beyond one line long. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\end{deletedParagraphs}

\begin{addedParagraphs}
Example added section - notice that word wrap is looking fine in this section without the sout addition.
\end{addedParagraphs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `environ` package or xparse `b` argument type to capture the whole environment body then put it inside the soul strikethrough command. Although I'm not sure if that suffices for `\cite` or similar either -- maybe post a MWE so we can more easily test answers?

Comment: Didn't test but it might be because you're using `\color` incorrectly, see [What is the difference between \textcolor and \color? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86039/what-is-the-difference-between-textcolor-and-color).

Comment: Okay that's not the cause. The actual cause is [macros - Problem with linebreak in combination with strikeout from the ulem package and newcommand - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430291/problem-with-linebreak-in-combination-with-strikeout-from-the-ulem-package-and-n). (or [How to underline text from a macro including a line break? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629950/how-to-underline-text-from-a-macro-including-a-line-break)